# Scrape select headings and inner text from a webpage using BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Source - a blog post URL

I want to get the inner text of both the Heading tags AND the body copy within that tag into a table output that looks like this

```
H2;{H2 tag inner tex}; {p tag(s) inner text}
H3;{H2 tag inner tex}; {p tag(s) inner text}
H2;{H2 tag inner tex}; {p tag(s) inner text}
H3;{H2 tag inner tex}; {p tag(s) inner text}
H4;{H2 tag inner tex}; {p tag(s) inner text}
...
```

Content of H2, H3, H4 tags are desired
And there might be multiple paragraphs within these tags, so getting them separated by a new line would be awesome.

Can BeautifulSoup do this?

I can get the innertext of the tags out, but don't know how to get the inner text of p tags out, especially when they are more than one. Or to format this so I can save as a CSV.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
website = requests.get('https://venngage.com/blog/landing-page-examples/')
preString =  {'h1': '', 'h2': '\t', 'h3':'\t\t', 'h4':'\t\t\t'}
soup = BeautifulSoup(website.content, 'html.parser')
tags = soup.find_all(['h1', 'h2', 'h3'])
for soups in tags:
    preStr = preString[soups.name] if soups.name in preString else ''
    print(preStr+soups.string)
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: yes, you can achieve this (with and without bs4), but what have you tried so far ?
the question needs sufficient code for a minimal reproducible example:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Thanks for your reply - Updated my post with what I tried

Comment: it looks like you are close with this:  `p_tags = soup.find_all(['p'])` would get this.

Comment: Thanks - yeah what I'm struggling with is how to format it in the form of a tabular output as described above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand exactly how you want your table organized (which paragraphs you want for each heading? are overlaps ok for nested headings?), but the following suggested solution will set a row for each header tag, and then loop through its siblings collecting all `p` tags until it hits another header tag:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas

website = requests.get('https://venngage.com/blog/landing-page-examples/')
preString =  {'h1': '', 'h2': '\t', 'h3':'\t\t', 'h4':'\t\t\t'}


htagNames = [k for k in preString.keys()]
htags = soup.find_all(htagNames)
# if you want from within a particular section
# htags = soup.select_one('article.post').find_all(htagNames) 

for h in htags:
    pStrings = []
    for tag in h.find_next_siblings(htagNames+['p']): 
        if tag.name == 'p' and tag.string is not None: 
            pStrings.append(tag.string)
        if tag.name in htagNames: break
    
    headingRows.append({
        'headingType': h.name, # 'headingText': h.string, 
        'headingText': preString[h.name] + h.get_text(' ' , strip=True),  
        'paragraphs': '\n'.join(pStrings)
    }) 

# can filter out heading with no paragraphs with
# headingRows = [hr for hr in headingRows if hr['paragraphs']]
        
# save as csv
pandas.DataFrame(headingRows).to_csv('hRows.csv', index=False)
```

or, if you're not sure that the `p` tags you want will share a parent tag with the header, then you can just blindly collect all the paragraphs until the next header:

```py
tags = soup.find_all(htagNames+['p']) 

lastTag = tags[-1]
headingRows = []
hInit = {'headingType': None, 'headingText': None, 'paragraphs': []}
curHeading = dict(hInit) # copy

for i, t in enumerate(tags): 
    if t.name == 'p' and t.string is not None: 
        curHeading['paragraphs'].append(t.string) 
    
    if t.name in preString: 
        curHeading['headingType'] = t.name
        #curHeading['preStr'] = preString[t.name]
        curHeading['headingText'] = preString[t.name] + t.get_text(' ' , strip=True) # + t.string
    
    if t == lastTag or tags[i+1].name in preString:
        # if you want possible paras before 1st heading, remove if condition
        if curHeading['headingType'] is not None :
            curHeading['paragraphs'] ='\n'.join(curHeading['paragraphs'])
            headingRows.append(curHeading)
        
        curHeading = dict(hInit) # copy
        curHeading['paragraphs'] = []
```

although, this runs the risk of getting paragraphs from a header-less section below...

---

results will look something like

[image: spreadsheet screenshot]

[excel automatically hides leading whitespaces, but dw the indents are still there for the headingtext column]

Comment: Thanks a ton for this. 

This works for some, but for a lot of blog post pages, it fails with the following error

'headingText': preString[h.name] + h.string, 
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "NoneType") to str
- -
SAMPLE URLS
https://www.shopify.com/blog/product-page
https://business.tutsplus.com/articles/product-landing-page-examples--cms-32174

Your help would be much appreciated

Comment: @Outbound try using `h.get_text(' ' , strip=True)` instead of `h.string` [I didn't consider `h_` tags with other tags nested inside]

Comment: This works awesome. I'm going to try creating a loop to see if I can feed it a list of URLs instead of a single one. Thanks for helping me get this far.